# What is wrong with the Youtube API (Invalid Request)?

Tags: php, youtube-api

When I try to upload the video using the youtube API, I get error "Invalid Request".

BUT!

When I upload any "image" instead of "video" it returns to me the status "200" and the video ID.

Why do I can't upload videos?

```
$eq = 'accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email='.$YOUTUBE_EMAIL.'&Passwd='.$YOUTUBE_PASS.'&service=youtube&source='.$API_NAME;
if ($fp = fsockopen ("ssl://www.google.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 20))
{
    $request ="POST /youtube/accounts/ClientLogin HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $request.="Host: www.google.com\r\n";
    $request.="Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $request.="Content-Length: ".strlen($eq)."\r\n";
    $request.="\r\n\r\n";
    $request.=$eq;
    fwrite($fp,$request,strlen($request));

    while (!feof($fp))
    $response.=fread($fp,8192);
    //fclose($fp);
}

preg_match("!(.*?)Auth=(.*?)\n!si",$response,$ok);
$AUTH_TOKEN = $ok[2];

$data = "<?xml version='1.0'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
    <media:group>
     <media:title type='plain'>test</media:title>
     <media:description type='plain'>test</media:description>
     <media:category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schema /2007/categories.cat'>People</media:category>
     <media:keywords>toast, wedding</media:keywords>
    </media:group>
</entry> ";

if ($fp = fsockopen ("gdata.youtube.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 20))
{
    $request ="POST /action/GetUploadToken HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request.="Host: gdata.youtube.com\r\n";
    $request.="Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $request.="Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n";
    $request .="Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$AUTH_TOKEN."\r\n";
    $request.="X-GData-Client: ".$API_NAME." \r\n";
    $request.="X-GData-Key: key=".$API_KEY." \r\n";
    $request.="\r\n";
    $request.=$data."\r\n";

    socket_set_timeout($fp, 10);
    fputs($fp,$request,strlen($request));
    $response = fread($fp,3280);
    fclose($fp);
}


preg_match('|<url>(.*)</url>|Uis', $response, $url);
preg_match('|<token>(.*)</token>|Uis', $response, $token);

print "
    <form action='".$url[1]."?nexturl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <input type='file' name='file'>
      <input type='hidden' name='token' value='".$token[1]."'>
      <input type='submit' value='go'>
    </form> ";
```

Comment: why don't you use youtube php client library to do this ?

Comment: I use ZEND library, but this variant doesn't work.

I get this error:


> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with
> message 'Expected response code 200,
> got 400 <?xml version='1.0'
> encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error><domain>yt:validation</domain><code>required</code><location
> type='xpath'>media:group/media:title/text()</location></error></errors>'
> in
> /home/switchoff/data/www/online-gid.ru/YouTubeAPI/Zend/Gdata/App.php:700
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/switchoff/data/www/online-gid.ru/YouTubeAPI/Zend/Gdata.php(219):

Comment: > Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('POST', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array,
> '<atom:entry xml...',
> 'application/ato...', NULL) #1
> /home/switchoff/data/www/online-gid.ru/YouTubeAPI/Zend/Gdata/App.php(886):
> Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('POST',
> 'http://gdata.yo...', Array,
> '<atom:entry xml...',
> 'application/ato...') #2
> /home/switchoff/data/www/online-gid.ru/YouTubeAPI/Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php(704):
> Zend_Gdata_App->post(Object(Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry),
> 'http://gdata.yo...') #3
> /home/switchoff/data/www/online-gid.ru/YouTubeAPI/test.php(56):

Comment: > Zend_Gdata_YouTube->getFormUplo in
> /home/switchoff/data/www/online-gid.ru/YouTubeAPI/Zend/Gdata/App.php
> on line 700

Comment: poelinca,do you have a working example?

Comment: @Nick - did you get this solved.  My working scripts just started exhibiting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Hahahah!! almost a year later, I think I found the fix.

your line has a space in it after "/schema" and before "/2007"

```
<media:category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schema /2007/categories.cat'>People</media:category>
```

it should be

```
<media:category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schema/2007/categories.cat'>People</media:category>
```

see the 2nd code block under: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading#Sending_a_Direct_Upload_API_Request